# XML helper/output of model data in 2.0?

Tags: xml, cakephp-2.0

My XML View files contain (for exporting records via XML):

```
 <records><?php echo $this->Xml->serialize($records); ?></records>
```

After upgrading to 2.0 I realized there is no Xml helper anymore.
But the Xml class itself doesnt seem to provide an equally powerful method anymore, either.
It only contains sth like

```
$Xml = Xml::fromArray($records, array('format' => 'attribute'));
...
<records><?php echo $Xml->asXML(); ?></records>
```

But that - of course - fails because it can only transform "one record at a time".
It also fails if I force it into a single parent key like

```
$records = array('records'=>$records);
```

first...

No clue how to get the XML export stuff working, again.
especially, as it seems, the expected input for the 2.0 XML class (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#Xml) is quite different from what the model returns (and would probably have to be transformed somehow).
Old structure (and like the model respectably):

```
$records = array(
    array('Project'=>array('field'=>'value', ...)),
    array('Project'=>array('field'=>'value', ...)),
);
```

New structure

```
$records = array(
    'projects' => array(
        'project' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 1, 'title' => 'Project 1',
                'industry' => array('id' => 1, 'name' => Industry 1')
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2, 'title' => 'Project 2',
                'industry' => array('id' => 2, 'name' => Industry 2')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Totally incompatible to what the model gives us, or so it seems.

Comment: Did you ever receive an answer or further clarification to this? I'm struggling with this myself and being a bit new to CakePHP I'm not making much headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to it is pretty simply I found out shortly after asking the question via http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2789-xml-view-defect

basically, you always need a single parent. so the old syntax could be seen as invalid. therefore upgrading and moving to the outlined new structure seems to be a requirement.